# How to add "else" to "foreach"?

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

i don't know how to add `else` to `foreach`!

here is my code:

```
<?php $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'actor' ); 
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'actor' );
        if( is_wp_error( $term_link ) )
        continue;
        echo '<a href="' . $term_link . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: and have you actually **tried anything** so far? by the way: `foreach` does not support `else`, but `if` does.

Comment: what you want to achieve ..... logically?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann - Interestingly, there were some suggestions that I saw recently proposing an `else` for `foreach`

Comment: @MarkBaker i've seen something similar to recently, i believe as part of twig, and it's not a bad idea - but as of now, most languages (including PHP), don't implement anything like it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try something similar:

```
<?php 
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'actor' ); 
    if ($terms) {
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            $term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'actor' );
            if ( is_wp_error( $term_link ) )
                continue;
            echo '<a href="' . $term_link . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
        }   
    } else {
        // do the work for else
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

For sake of completeness, there is an old RFC (10 years old) that proposes loop+else:

https://wiki.php.net/rfc/loop_else

Comment: bro, it was for 5 years ago :|

Answer (score 0):

`foreach` is a loop. `else` is part of a conditional statement. It looks like you just want a conditional inside your loop. This would just be a standard conditional.

```
if ($a > $b) {
  echo "a is greater than b";
} else {
  echo "a is NOT greater than b";
}
```

I assume you want to `break` the loop in that case.

Comment: the foreach/else paradigm is not common but it is not unheard of.  Take a look at https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#the-else-clause for an example of this.  I know that "twig is not a real programming language" but that doesn't invalidate the idea being a valid concept.  It is also used as a python concept: https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html.